# Execute a particular command only for the first time in a shell

Tags: linux, shell

I have a script.
I need to execute a particular command only for the first time i try to run this script in my shell. Otherwise, it should not be executed and the rest of the commands should be done.

How can i implement this? All pointers are welcome.

Thanks,
Sen

---

This is a code which i tried to implement :

```
start_time=`date +%s`
echo $script_instance
if [ `echo $script_instance` == true ]; then
  end_time=`date +%s`
  echo '#########################################################################'
  echo '# Build Date : '`date`
  echo '# Compilation time : '`expr $end_time - $start_time` s
  echo '#########################################################################'
else
  echo '-------------------------------------------------------------------------'
  echo 'Updating the APIs'
  echo '-------------------------------------------------------------------------'
fi
script_instance=true
export $script_instance
```

---

This is not working correctly. Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an environment variable the first time you're running the script:

- csh/tcsh: `setenv MYVARIABLE something`
- bash: `export MYVARIABLE="something"`

Then check with an if-clause if the variable is set. If so, do the other stuff, if not then this is the first time the script is executed.

Comment: how to check if the variable is set or not?

Comment: @Marco Mariani thx, added the bash version. @Sen you can check if a string is empty with -z: `if [ -z "$MYVARIABLE" ] then; echo "Variable is empty"; fi`

Answer (score 3):

You should probably check for the *effect* of the possible script execution, not the mere fact that it has run.
For instance, does it build anything? If so, check for the intended output.

Otherwise, if anything fails, just create a flag file with `touch $HOME/.some_hidden_file` and check for its existence.

Setting variables is not persistent in UNIX.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the context, but maybe you can just remove executable permission from the script at the end:

```
chmod a-x $0
```

Then, until you `chmod a+x <scriptname>` again, you will not be able to execute it. You will get "Permission denied".

**Note after comment:**

In this case, you can split script into always.sh and firstonly.sh. Use `chmod a-x $0` in firstonly.sh and in always.sh do:

```
[ -x firstonly.sh ] && ./firstonly.sh
```

Alternatively, you can use some kind of flag file as suggested in other answers.

Comment: Ok.. thanks.. But what i want is like i have a script file where i have a two set of commands -  one set need to be executed only for the first time i try to run this script in a shell. If i try to run the same script in the same shell, the first set should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Run this once and it prints one two.
Run it again and it only prints two.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

if [ ! -f ONCE.txt]
then
    echo one
    touch ONCE.txt
fi
echo two
```

As mentioned by others, the detection whether the once-only operation has been successfully executed once would ideally depend on a difference resulting from that operation. It could be a file, or directory, or a harmless installed command that can be run to tell the difference.