# How to run a command only on remote login to linux

Tags: linux, bash, yum, rhel, login-script

I want my system to display available updates when I log in.

What I did is to setup a cron job to run daily to save the output of `yum list updates` to a file. Now I need to find a place for a command to `cat` this file which is run *only when I login* to the Linux machine.

I'm running RedHat Enterprise Linux and bash.

I'd like solutions for both running it on every login or only on remote logins, and also for all users and for a specific user - so I can choose the best one and so that this information is here for others. Right now I most need to be for *all users* and *only* when the first login.

Comment: I tried placing the command in `/etc/profile.d/xxx.sh` but this runs also when I invoke a `bash` shell inside the current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append the command you would like to run to the `/etc/profile` file. This will make it run for all users on login.

For remote logins (through SSH), you can modify the `Banner` parameter of the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

Also, modifying `/etc/issue` and `/etc/motd` might do what you're looking for as well.

As far as running a script only the first time a user logs in, this question was answered before here: [Execute a particular command only for the first time in a shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872234/execute-a-particular-command-only-for-the-first-time-in-a-shell)

Answer (score 1):

Put the call in the /etc/profile file.  This file is run at login for all bash users.

Comment: I want it to run for *all* users.

Comment: see my comment. This is run also when invoking a nested bash shell.